# How to call a viewcontroller in other class using KGModal

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on an app. The app is in the swift. Now the problem is I'm trying to represent a view controller from another view using the KGModel.
Lets say that are two view controller ViewA and ViewB. Now if i set the viewB as the initial viewcontroller then it's working fine. All the delegate of the tableview controller called successfully but if try to call the ViewB from viewA then the table view always return empty. Is any one know how to call the other view controller in the current view using KGmodel. Thanks in advance.

**Code To Call ViewB from ViewA**

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoveToReviewView") as? ReviewViewController
    controller?.assignValue = self
    presentController(controller!)

  func presentController(_ controller: UIViewController) {
    let ret = self.view.frame
    controller.view.frame.size.width = ret.size.width - ret.size.width/4
    controller.view.frame.size.height = ret.size.height/2


    KGModal.sharedInstance().show(withContentView: controller.view, andAnimated: true)
}
```

**The output is**

[image]